# Computer build for scientific or big data computing

Tags: parallel-computing, computational-physics, hpc

I'm wanting to build a computer for scientific or big data computing (Python, Fortran, Matlab) and I was hoping to get some advice on the type of processor, memory, graphics, etc I would need.

I understand clusters would be ideal for most of this but that is not an option.

What are some of the pros and cons for different processors? Are some processors built for gaming? What type of graphics card would I need? Other than Solidworks I won't be messing with gaming and what not.

Any help would be appreciated. I understand some older post are on this subject but yearly components get a lot better so I would like some updated information.

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't given any indication of how much money you have to spend or what kind of problems you'll be solving or how large your working data sets will be.  It's really impossible to answer this question.

Comment: I was wanting to keep this post general so I could figure out where to start learning. I've heard that most CPU's now are designed for gaming not number crunching and I was hoping to learn a little more about that. Anyways, I'll be doing mostly data scraping and data manipulation. I would estimate I will be handling a matrix of maximum size (2GB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curtis Northcutt has a guide [here](http://l7.curtisnorthcutt.com/the-best-4-gpu-deep-learning-rig) which was [much loved](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/ayd01o/p_i_built_lambdas_12500_deep_learning_rig_for_6200/) on Reddit. This question is very general, though, so it is difficult to really answer it well. As such, it may not be the best fit for this site.